# How to use useEffect in class based component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I basically want to handle loading state in my react-native app with class base component and somehow as we can't useEffect I am unable to do the task. I have onMount and onChamge as below

```
componentDidMount = async () => {
    const companyId = await companyApi.getCompanyId();
    this.setState({ entityId: companyId });

    try {
      const response = await network.getJewelleryPriceSettings({
        entityId: this.state.entityId,
        entityType: this.state.entityType,
      });
      const data = await response;
      this.setState({ jewelleryPriceDisplayStatus: data });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

how can I handle the loading state ie I want a loading animation that stays till the time I can fetch the details.
Please let me know if you need more code thanks for the help.

Comment: Why do you need `useEffect`? You can update the loading state in the existing `componentDidMount`

Comment: You can't use hooks in class components. Hooks are _only_ available in function components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

useEffect is a hook that is used in functional components, and it can't be used with class-based components. `componentDidMount` will be used in place of `useEffect` in class-based components.
You can learn more about it [here](https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/8747/react-lifecycle-methods-render-and-componentdidmount)

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    entityId: null,
    entityType: null,
    jewelleryPriceDisplayStatus: null,
    isLoading: true // Add a new state variable to indicate whether the data is loading or not
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const companyId = await companyApi.getCompanyId();
    this.setState({ entityId: companyId });

    try {
      const response = await network.getJewelleryPriceSettings({
        entityId: this.state.entityId,
        entityType: this.state.entityType,
      });
      const data = await response;
      this.setState({ jewelleryPriceDisplayStatus: data, isLoading: false }); // Set isLoading to false after data is fetched
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      this.setState({ isLoading: false }); // Set isLoading to false in case of error
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { jewelleryPriceDisplayStatus, isLoading } = this.state;

    if (isLoading) {
      return <LoadingAnimation />; // Render a loading animation while the data is being fetched
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {/* Render the component's contents here */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

May be this can give you some idea.